# Usi dell'esclamazione "hai voglia"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, exclamations

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> GIOVANNI     Ma di quanti mesi è? Domenica scorsa l’ho vista e non mi pareva... 
>   ANTONIA     E quando mai hai capito qualcosa tu delle donne? A parte che domenica scorsa è già una settimana fa... e in una settimana, **hai voglia** che cosa può capitare!

Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000981.jpg) ho trovato questa spiegazione sull'uso dell'interiezione "hai voglia":

> **6.** Inter. *Hai voglia!*: per indicare l’inutilità o la dif­ficoltà di insistere in un tentativo, in un proposito. 
>         *Imbriani*, 1-119:  Innamorata  di  questo...  Sì!  Aspetta, ch’io 
>   venga  stasera!  Aspetta,  aspè!  Hai  voglia  d’aspettare!  Il  corbo!  *Savinio*, 413: Ha voglia  lui di leggersi  e rileggersi il teatro com­pleto  di  Ibsen! *Cassola*, 2-373:  Hai  voglia  prima  che  passi  la giornata!

Tuttavia, nel testo di Fo, non mi sembra che ci sia niente di cui si possa indicare l'inutilità o la difficoltà di insistere nel proposito. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: ci sono altri usi dell'esclamazione "hai voglia"? Che senso ha nel brano sopra citato?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il significato nel brano non è tanto diverso dalla definizione che hai trovato sul dizionario; il personaggio sta dicendo che in una settimana tante, troppe cose possono succedere per poterle prevedere o anche solo discuterne o farne un elenco.

Il senso di "inutilità" è secondo me questo; è come se una parte della frase fosse stata omessa, una cosa del tipo

> [...] in una settimana, hai voglia (*prevedere*) che cosa può capitare!

oppure

> [...] in una settimana, hai voglia (*discutere di*) che cosa può capitare!

Un altro uso comune di questa esclamazione si trova nella risposta di @persson.

Answer (score 6):

Si usa anche (e mi sembra strano che il dizionario non ne parli) nel senso di "eccome!", "certamente!" (cfr. "i tant!" o "¡y tanto!"):

> – Ti è piaciuta la pasta? 
>   – Hai voglia! Ne ho mangiati due piatti!

Questo significato è menzionato per esempio in questo [articolo della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_759.html).

Comment: Forse anche in questo caso, come quello che ha spiegato @RiccardoDeContardi, questo "hai voglia" deve essere interpretato come "hai voglia di discutere su questo".

Comment: Può essere, io lo vedo anche come "eccome che ne possono capitare di cose..." però effettivamente è abbastanza sfumato.

Comment: Ho trovato questo [articolo della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_759.html) che menziona il significato che hai il spiegato nella tua risposta. Forse potresti arricchirla includendo le informazioni di questo articolo.